# opencv framework into XCode: Header-Linkers not working

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, git, opencv

I guess I did a terrible mistake by assuming that the opencv framework can get updated and easily linked into an existing XCode-project again. The mistake happens at Step-Nr2 of the guidance on how to get opencv & make the XCode find header-files etc and finally create and install the opencv framework.

The 3 Steps are (...having a terminal on Mac opened and writing:)

Step1:
    cd ~/
    git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
---> This one went through successfully

Step2:
    cd /
    sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer Developer
---> This one fails
The error message is:  ln: Developer/Developer: File exists

Step3:
    cd ~/
    python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios
---> This one went through successfully

Now, since Step-Nr2 did not go through, I get the compiler-error now in XCode that

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>   // --> assumption: StepNr2 did not go through and therefore header-linker do not work (what is there to do ???)
```

cannot be found ! It seems to me that the symbolic link for Xcode to let OpenCV build scripts and find the compiler, header files etc. does no longer work for the newly integrated opencv-framework. It did work for an old one. But Step-Nr2 would be needed again successully !

Can anybody tell me what to do in order to do Step2 sucessfully (in a case like mine where it was carried out previously a couple of weeks ago). What files do I  need to delete and where can I find them ? (I cannot find the "Developer File" for example (as ist sais that already existed). Where can it be found and deleted ?? Or what do I need to do ?

Or can the settings even be made in the XCode project itself ? Where and how would I do that ?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: have you tried using cocoapods for installation of opencv ?

Comment: @PetrV: Thank you for the hint. I am not sure if that is necessary. Again, I had the installation working properly with the 3 github-steps as described in my entry. But after deleting the opencv-framework an re-installing it, that's when the problems occurred. For some reason Step2 does not perform again. But I cannot find the Developer-File mentioned...